# Listing installed applications in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, social-networking

In my application I need to share an item through various way (like facebook, twitter, linkedin etc). So I need to list the application installed in my phone show that I can share via any one appplication. So can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to know what other applciations are installed on a phone. Having access to this information would be a potential data privacy issue.

Comment: but i need to share something through either of the application installed in the phone.

Comment: If the platform doesn't support it then you can't do it. You'll have to add the sharing functionality directly into your app.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Phone 7 has builtin support for this kind of actions with the [launchers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769550%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) / [choosers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769543%28v=VS.92%29.aspx). Within the list of launchers you will find the [ShareStatusTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh394027%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) which is opening the builtin 'share your status' control. This control checks your phone device for the profiles/networks to which you have connected. By using the Status property of the Task you can than fill in the message you want to share. In the opened control you can than choose on which networks you want to share your message.

See below code sample on how to use this task:

```
ShareStatusTask shareStatusTask = new ShareStatusTask();

shareStatusTask.Status = "Share my status on different networks";

shareStatusTask.Show();
```

NOTE: If you start a launcher from your app, your app will be deactived. Normally after completing the taks your app will be reactivated. For the overview of Launchers / choosers you can have a look at [Launchers and Choosers Overview for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769542%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)

Comment: i am using SDK7.0 so couldnot get the Launchers/Choosers for ShareStatusTesk. So any other suggestions.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you are using 7.0?

Comment: The SDK is not specific to a Windows version, I would suggest that if you don't have a specific reason update the SDK and the app your building to version 7.1. (Mango is delivered to almost every device right now, and all new phones will have WP7.1 installed.)